# Multiple removal PDO, php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Need to remove a lot of records. It works:

```
$db->exec("DELETE from link WHERE link_id IN (35, 40, 50)");  
$ercode=$db->errorCode();
```

How can I get the number from the string or array?
It code removes only the first number (19)

```
$string = "19, 20";
$count=$db->prepare("delete from link where item=:myid");
$count->bindParam(":myid", $string, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$count->execute();
```

Comment: Plain PDO cannot bind arrays. You'll have to use a wrapper or reinvent your own utility code to insert a list of `?` placeholders and bind individual array entries.

Comment: If that syntax was allowed, how could MySQL decide whether you want `'19', '20'` or `'19, 20'`?